# Value being returned from function prematurely due to asynchronous functions

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

So I would like to return the value json10 after both query.on have been computed. However query.on is asynchronous so I return from my function before json10 can be computed. How can I structure this function so the query.on's are completed before I return from the function?

```
function getJsn(mystr){
   var query = doc.query(mystr);
   var json10;
   query.on("row", function (row, result) {
      result.addRow(row);
   });
   query.on("end", function (result) {
      var json1 = JSON.stringify(result.rows, null, "    ");
      json10= json1;
      var  json = JSON.parse(json1);
      for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
         var obj = json[i];
      }
   })
   return json10;
}
```

Comment: I have but have not been able to figure it out

Comment: You will want to use a promise, check out https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/231/promises#t=201707291926141558833

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use a callback since you are async inside `getJsn`

```
function getJsn(mystr, cb){
   var query = doc.query(mystr);
   var json10;
   query.on("row", function (row, result) {
      result.addRow(row);
   });
   query.on("end", function (result) {
      var json1 = JSON.stringify(result.rows, null, "    ");
      json10= json1;
      var  json = JSON.parse(json1);
      for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
         var obj = json[i];
      }
      cb(json10);
   })
}
```

and call it like this

```
getJsn(someStr, function(ret) {
    console.log( ret ); // this should return json10
});
```